# Package combined C++/Python software

Tags: python, packaging

I would like to package a software that contains both C++ and Python code. The C++ headers and libraries compile fine on launchpad and are properly installed (thanks to some `.install` files).

On the Python side of things, the names of the (raw) install files would be

```
/build/buildd/trilinos-11.1~20130107/debian/tmp/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/PyTrilinos/AztecOO.py
/build/buildd/trilinos-11.1~20130107/debian/tmp/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/PyTrilinos/AztecOO.pyc
/build/buildd/trilinos-11.1~20130107/debian/tmp/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/PyTrilinos/_AztecOO.so
```

What's the proper way to have them installed? Should I also create an `.install` file listing those files, or is there way to use `dh_python2`?

Answer (score 1):

Both. First you install them, then you call `dh_python2`.

`dh_python` will move things around, remove `.pyc` files, and handle byte-compilation at installation time.

Comment: What do you mean by "then"? Is a dedicated `install` target in `debian/rules` necessary that controls the installation and also calls `dh_python2`?

Comment: `dh_install` is to put them in the right package. You need to make sure that `dh_python2` gets called, but that usually wouldn't happen in an `install` target...

Answer (score 1):

The usual thing to do is to create a `setup.py` file and then call this from your rules file. With `dh`, your rules file, at least the python part, can then be as simple as

```
%:
        dh $@ --with python2 --buildsystem=python_distutils --install-layout=deb
```